# Pika: How to get a return value from a callback function?

Tags: rabbitmq, pika

I have a callback function in my program that I need to check success/failure. How can I do this?
In my example below, where does failure_code go? 
My snippet:

```
def mq_callback(job_id, ch, method, body):
  # Do some stuff. But if the stuff fails...
   return failure_code

channel.basic_consume(
        queue='some queue',
        on_message_callback=lambda ch, method, properties, body: mq_callback(job_id, ch, method, body),
        auto_ack=False
    )

channel.start_consuming()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All in this link: https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-six-python.html

We create a class for calling requests then wait until the response id equal to the correlation_id that was sent before.